# Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match nextjs on chrome browser

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When today morning opening my current working project and run on dev server on chrome I got this "Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server". Then I tried so many solutions mentioned in nextjs documents and stackoverflow. But I coundn't find a working solution. Then I just created new next js project and tried and got the same error. Error was,

```
react-dom.development.js?160d:94 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <body>.
    at div
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:124:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:303:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:310:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:339:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:346:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:258:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:40:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:12:34)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:18:11)
    at body
    at html
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:53:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:19:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:97:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:28:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:40:11)
    at AppRouter
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:113:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:130:11)
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js?160d:94
react-dom.development.js?160d:14706 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (react-dom.development.js?160d:14706:1)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (react-dom.development.js?160d:14756:1)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js?160d:22897:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?160d:24709:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?160d:4246:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?160d:4295:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?160d:4359:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?160d:31944:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?160d:30853:1)
    at workLoopConcurrent (react-dom.development.js?160d:30839:1)
    at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js?160d:30797:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?160d:29844:1)
    at workLoop (index.js?82e4:10:3922)
    at flushWork (index.js?82e4:10:3630)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (index.js?82e4:10:1812)
react-dom.development.js?160d:94 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js?160d:94
3react-dom.development.js?160d:31301 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (react-dom.development.js?160d:14706:1)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (react-dom.development.js?160d:14756:1)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js?160d:22897:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?160d:24709:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?160d:31919:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?160d:30853:1)
    at workLoopConcurrent (react-dom.development.js?160d:30839:1)
    at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js?160d:30797:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?160d:29844:1)
    at workLoop (index.js?82e4:10:3922)
    at flushWork (index.js?82e4:10:3630)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (index.js?82e4:10:1812)
react-dom.development.js?160d:22844 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js?160d:22844:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?160d:24692:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?160d:31919:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?160d:30853:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js?160d:30689:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js?160d:30654:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js?160d:29970:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?160d:29857:1)
    at workLoop (index.js?82e4:10:3922)
    at flushWork (index.js?82e4:10:3630)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (index.js?82e4:10:1812)
```

My default browser is chrome and then I tried in edge and brave browser and amazingly they don't give me those errors.

Code sandbox for testing project: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/dwalker93/next13/draft/condescending-frog

In chrome browser
[image: In chrome browser]

In Edge Browser
[image: In Edge Browser]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after spending few hours, i found the problem and that was a chrome extension doing that.

Comment: I had the same problem, stupid extension made spend a lot of time